# how to represent a CSV File as a data structure in a C# program

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a csv file I am going to read from disk. I do not know up front how many columns or the names of the columns.
Any thoughts on how I should represent the fields. Ideally I want to say something like,

string Val =  DataStructure.GetValue(i,ColumnName).
where i is the ith Row.

Oh just as an aside I will be parsing using the TextFieldParser class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Are the names of columns always in the first row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds as if you would need a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) which has a `Rows` and `Columns` property.

So you can say:

```
string Val = table.Rows[i].Field<string>(ColumnName);
```

A `DataTable` is a table of in-memory data. It can be used strongly typed (as suggested with the `Field` method) but actually it stores it's data as objects internally.

You could use [this parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) to convert the csv to a DataTable.

**Edit**: I've only just seen that you want to use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). Here's a possible simple approach to convert a csv to a `DataTable`:

```
var table = new DataTable();
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(File.OpenRead(path)))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new[]{","};
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    // load DataColumns from first line 
    String[] headers = parser.ReadFields();
    foreach(var h in headers)
            table.Columns.Add(h);
    // load all other lines as data '
    String[] fields;
    while ((fields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        table.Rows.Add().ItemArray = fields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column names are in the first row read that and store in a `Dictionary<string, int>` that maps the column name to the column index.

You could then store the remaining rows in a simple structure like `List<string[]>`.
To get a column for a row you'd do `csv[rowIndex][nameToIndex[ColumnName]];`

`nameToIndex[ColumnName]` gets the column index from the name, `csv[rowIndex]` gets the row (string array) we want.

This could of course be wrapped in a class.

Comment: this is pretty clever too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the csv parser if you want, but a text parser is something very easy to do by yourself if you need customization.

For you need, i would use one (or more) Dictionnary. At least one to have the PropertyString --> column index. And maybe the reverse one column index--> PropertyString if needed.

When i parse a file for csv, i usually put the result in a list while parsing, and then in an array once complete for speed reasons (List.ToArray()).